# How do i password protect a page in refinery cms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, refinerycms

Basically i am trying to set up a password for a single page in refinery. Is there an extension which can do such a thing for me automatically or should i override internal parts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with a default install of Refinery, you'll have to write an engine or override some internal methods/before filters to do this.  Unpack the refinerycms-core gem and look at the crud.rb file, where all the crudify methods are generated. It should help shed some light on what you'll need to do to make this happen.

Or look here: https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/core/lib/refinery/crud.rb